# Oracle SQL pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table:

```
create table t(
xparam varchar2(10),
xtime  date,
xvalue varchar2(10) 
);
```

with data

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('param1', sysdate, 'ok');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('param1', sysdate-1, 'soso');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('param1', sysdate-2, 'well');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('param2', sysdate, 'perfect');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('param2', sysdate-1, 'good');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('param2', sysdate-2, 'ups');
```

so it looks like:

```
param1  29-Dec-13   ok
param1  28-Dec-13   soso
param1  27-Dec-13   well
param2  29-Dec-13   perfect
param2  28-Dec-13   good
param2  27-Dec-13   ups
```

is there a way to represent them in

```
------- 29-Dec-13   28-Dec-13   27-Dec-13
param1  ok          soso        well
param2  perfect     good        ups
```

?

Similar questions were asked already, but they suggested to list all columns in where clause; I would like to avoid that.

Suppose there are data for several years, and new coming each month,
so would like to avoid listing all possible dates in "when '20/12/2013' then 20122013 ..", and manually adding new column each month.

Similarly, there are a lot - like thousands - of parameters too;
so would prefer to not to list them as well.

UPD: after thinking a while... ok, those dates are monthly, and actually I can create those columns in forward, for some years; no problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "standard" way to do that, because it would make the column-count nonconstant, which violates more or less all API conventions.

If you'd be able to settle for the, say, 20 newest, you could probably do something in a PL/SQL procedure that selects the 20 newest xtimes, concatenate them to a string, surround that string by `create table helpertable as select  <statement to get the 20 newest columns from t>`, and `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` that string. Then `select *` from the helpertable.

Thinking about it, there's probably no real reason why the column count in helpertable should be constant, if your PL/SQL procedure drops it before creating it. Just make sure you don't exceed the maximum number of columns possible in one table.